# How can I make my layout load time more efficient?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have a layout with 4 tabs, the first tab has the home screen of the app, loads 4 imageviews for the icons of other activities.  The second tab loads a webview (very basic one) as does the third tab.  The final tab loads a map.  The app loads very slow, takes about 11 seconds, and when I debug in Eclipse almost the entire time is spent on setContentView, but I can't figure out what in my layout is taking so long to load.

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                >
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/HomeButtonEvents" 
                    android:src="@drawable/eventsicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                    android:paddingBottom="95dp"
                    android:clickable="true" 
                    />
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/CancelledClasses" 
                    android:src="@drawable/cancelledicon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                    />
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/CourseSchedule" 
                    android:src="@drawable/coursesicon"
                    android:layout_width="141dp" 
                    android:layout_height="139dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                    />
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/POTD" 
                    android:src="@drawable/potdicon"
                    android:layout_width="294dp" 
                    android:layout_height="247dp"
                    android:paddingTop="45dp" 
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/CourseSchedule" 
                    />
<!--            <ImageView -->
<!--                android:id="@+id/potdview"-->
<!--                android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--                android:paddingTop="0dp" -->
<!--                android:paddingRight="1dp"-->
<!--                android:paddingBottom="150dp" -->
<!--                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
<!--                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" -->
<!--                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/CourseSchedule" -->
<!--                /> -->
            </RelativeLayout>

            <WebView 
                android:id="@+id/tab2" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" 
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I formatted your code to be more readable. I don't know that this is your problem in particular, but you can't have comment lines (`<!-- -->`) within an XML tag. You need to simply have `<!--<ImageView` closing with `/>-->` to comment out that block.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tip, that hadn't been affecting the problem, I had just been using the toggle comment feature in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions would be to split the 4 tabs into separate activities unless you absolutely had to have them as tabs.  If you wish to have them as tabs, then perhaps load the tab content dynamically when the tab is focused.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have too many Layout objects. I believe you should be able to do everything with just a TabHost and the RelativeLayout.

Comment: I tried following your suggestion and removing LinearLayout, it trimmed 2-3 seconds off the load time; however, then the tab widget gets placed at the top instead of the bottom, plus the rest of the view fills the entire screen, so the tab widget is blocking part of the view.  From what I've read, don't you need to have LinearLayout and FrameLayout?  I'm not sure what other parts I could eliminate to get everything to work on the view...

Comment: Correction: LinearLayout didn't actually save any time, when I put it back in there was no change.